# Excel: Filter by Substrings

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, dropdownlist

I have a list of movies in an Excel table. In one column, titled "Genre", the movie genre is shown. A movie can have one, or several genres, separated by commata (and sorted alphabetically):

[image]

Now, when I feel like watching a horror movie, I want to display only movies that contain, say, "Horror", "Thriller", AND "Fantasy".

However, using the standard "Sort & Filter" function of MS Excel, it treats every combinations of genres differently (see above). The list is about 200 entries long: "Action", "Action, Adventure, Biography", "Action, Adventure, Comedy" etc., alphabetically. (If there are $n$ genres, and at most 3 genres per movie, then there will be about $nCr(n, 3)$ possible genre combinations, save some unrealistic combinations, but still). So, to display all horror movies, I have to go through the list and manually tick all entries that contain the string "Horror".

Note that there is the interface of the built-in "custom Auto-filter" in the below screenshot, and I can display movies that contain Drama and Horror (using wildcards to ignore other tags), but this interface does not allow for multiple ORs, just ANDs and at most one OR), and is much less user-friendly to access and adjust the search in this way, rather than to use a dropdown menu.

[image]

What I want is to be able to filter the genre using a dropdown list that recognizes that the current >200 different values in the column are just combinations of the same ~15 genres. In this list, I would only tick "Horror" and "Thriller" and "Fantasy" once, and get all movies displayed that contain all these substrings (or any one of them, depending on specification), no matter whether further genres are "Crime", "Action" etc.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: Could you use different columns for each genre? So you have "Horror" in L, "Drama" in M and so on?

Comment: The entire table is the output of an API request that gets this information out of the internet, and gets repeated/refreshed every so often. Thus, adding columns to split up the genre would be unfeasible. Furthermore, I would want to do the same thing with the "Actors" column, which would add many more columns than genre, making the table unnecessarily large across.

Comment: It would be possible to use another worksheet in the same file, though, for any "background" setup of a new dropdown list.

Comment: A "helper" sheet is often a option.  However, you would probably need to set an upper limit to how many Genres and Actors you want to track since that would determine the number of columns in your helper sheet.